# Javascript test results. can anyone explain them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, optimization

I was recently writing a blog post about checking if jquery elements exist before binding event handlers, I did a quick jsfiddle [which you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/atmd/ecMhG/4/)

The thing I dont understand, is that the results show (using chrome to measure in microseconds) that test 2 is a lot faster then test 1.

You'll see from the jsfiddle that test 2 checks the existent of the matching before binding a click event

TEST 1 is:

```
console.time('time_1');
    $('.yep').click(function() {
      alert('clicked');
    });
    console.timeEnd('time_1');
```

test 1 just tried to bind the event

TEST 2:

```
console.time('time_2');
if ($('.yep').length) {
  $('.yep').click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
}
console.timeEnd('time_2');
```

test 2 check the element exists before binding.

I am running the two bits of code on some, 87 I think 'section' elemenets, one of which has a class of 'yep'

I cant really see why the second test is faster, as its doing more work.

results:

```
time_1: 0.856ms 
time_2: 0.146ms
```

Can anyone shed some light and help out a confused developer.

thanks

n.b please dont reply with alternative ways to bind click events in jquery, the .click is just used as a simple test

Comment: That's not a reliable manner of comparing performance. Try [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/event-binding-timing)

Comment: I'm confused. Which is test one and which is test two? Do they appear in the right order in the question?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: No, test2 is the first test in the question.

Comment: Thanks @David Hedlund. atmd, that's bound to confuse. Suggest you add comments to make it clear which case is faster and which is slower.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Sorry, Iv not made it very clear. the rush to get the question out. Have edited it to make more sense.

Comment: @atmd, much clearer now.

Comment: @DavidHedlund i did do jsperf first http://jsperf.com/checking-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary thing going on here is that the *first* time you query a selector, the engine has to do more work than subsequent queries, which can sometimes be cached. If you [reverse the first two tests](http://jsfiddle.net/ecMhG/6/), you'll find that whichever one runs first tends to be the slower one.

Despite that, and mostly as a side note, in test 2 you're querying the DOM **twice**, first to check the `length`, and then to hook up the handler. If the query is cached it doesn't matter much, but still, just do it once:

```
console.time('time_x');
var yep = $('.yep');
if (yep.length) {
  yep.click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
}
console.timeEnd('time_x');
```

Note, though, that calling `click` on a jQuery set with no elements in it is a harmless no-op (not an error or anything), so there's no need for the `length` check unless you're *also* doing something else you haven't shown.

Comment: TJ, are you sure you've got the two cases round the right way? See my comments above.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: I worked on the basis of the results of the fiddle, which has the tests in a reasonable order and behaves as I outline above. The first test quoted in the question is test 2, which is the second test in the fiddle. (I'm the one who upvoted your comment about the question being very confused.)

Comment: TJ, OK what you say makes 100% sense. The question doesn't.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: I just noticed that I said "test 1" in the answer where I should have said "test 2"! Thank you.

Comment: TJ, notwithstanding the fiddle, then why should test 2 be faster then test 1?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: See my first paragraph.

Comment: TJ, OK but then your para2 should pull in the opposite direction. The majority effect is the para1 effect, DESPITE the para2 effect. ie, they are not additive.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was under the impression that it would only be cahced if I assigned the result to a variable, does the jquery core do this internally?

Comment: @atmd: It's deeper than that, it's in the browser selector engine. Selector engines cache queries, not least because people do things like your test 2 a lot. :-) For instance, try this in the console of your favorite browser: `document.getElementsByTagName("div") === document.getElementsByTagName("div")`. You'll find that **the same** `NodeList` instance is returned by both calls, so the result is `true`. Not just equivalent ones, the **same** one. (This isn't true for `querySelectorAll` because it returns *static* node lists, but internally you can bet those results are cached too.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I never know that. thanks. One thing I don't get though is that when you add the click event, is jquery not searching the dom for those elements? if the element doesnt exist, surely time is still being spent searching for those elements?

Comment: @atmd: No, the search occurs during the `$()` call, not during the `click()` call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so doing $('.doesntExist').click() does still search for the element, nothing then can be saved by checking if the element exists, as you'll do a search either way. Thanks for all your help.